# vendor/assets/stylesheets doesn't exist

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, css, ruby-on-rails-3

In my rails app directory, vendor/plugins and vendor/assets/stylesheets exist (both of those are empty).  I would like to create the javascripts folder.  Can I just create this manually or do I need to run any terminal commands?  Thanks

Comment: There's no such thing as a command in HTML/CSS to create a JS folder in RoR. I added a RoR tag to your question but feel free to also add the javascript tag if needed

Comment: Yes sorry I meant a rails command, late night

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just create the `javascripts` folder manually - there are no special commands.

Comment: do I copy the application.js file from /assets to /vendor?

Comment: Generally no - you should be able to require assets from the `vendor/javascripts` directory from within the `/assets/javascripts/application.js` just name them like normal with `//= require xxx` and Rails should find them as the `vendor` directory is automatically on the load path.